# Modelling membrane evolution over time

Tags: matlab, numpy

I am trying to model the time evolution of a membrane based on the following code in MATLAB.
[image]

The basic outline is that the evolution is based on a differential equation

[image]

where `j=0,1` and `x^0 = x`, `x^1 = y` and `x^j(s_i) = x^j_i`.

My code is the following.

```
import numpy as np  
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

R0 = 5 #radius
N = 360 #number of intervals

x0 = 2*np.pi*R0/(N/2) #resting membrane lengths

phi = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi, num=360, dtype=float)
R1 = R0 + 0.5*np.sin(20*phi)

X = R1*np.cos(phi)
Y = R1*np.sin(phi)

L = np.linspace(-1,358, num=360, dtype=int)
R = np.linspace(1,360, num=360,dtype=int) #right and left indexing vectors
R[359] = 0

X = R1*np.cos(phi)
Y = R1*np.sin(phi)

plt.plot(X,Y)
plt.axis("equal")
plt.show()

ds = 1/N
ds2 = ds**2

k = 1/10
w = 10**6

for i in range(0,20000):
    lengths = np.sqrt( (X[R]-X)**2 + (Y[R]-Y)**2 )
    
    Ex = k/ds2*(X[R] - 2*X + X[L] - x0*( (X[R]-X)/lengths - (X-X[L])/lengths[L]) )
    
    Ey = k/ds2*(Y[R] - 2*Y + Y[L] - x0*( (Y[R]-Y)/lengths - (Y-Y[L])/lengths[L]) )
    
    X = X + 1/w*Ex
    Y = Y + 1/w*Ey

plt.plot(X,Y)
plt.axis("equal")
plt.show()
```

The model is supposed to devolve into a circular membrane, as below

[image]

but this is what mine does

[image]

Comment: Try `axis equal` to scale x and y axes equally. This makes them comparable and makes a circle be circular.

Comment: That works a bit, but the membrane is supposed to be a complete circle at the end, rather than looking like a flower, as in mine.

Comment: Yeah, that was just one minor issue I noticed in your graph. I’m not planning to debug your program for you, you should learn to do this for yourself. In my experience, strange intersections in simulation results are usually caused by step sizes that are too large.

Comment: So I tried to debug my code and realised that one of the issues is that the lengths of the intervals weren't being updated in the loop. I fixed this but there still seems to be an issue. I even changed my code to make it look like the source code in MATLAB but it's still not working. Can you please help? I don't understand what's different in my code and the source code.

Comment: Please read: ["Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5698672)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of `x0` is wrong.
In the Matlab code, it is equal to

```
x0 = 2*pi*R/N/2  # which is pi*R/N
```

while in your Python code it is

```
x0 = 2*np.pi*R0/(N/2)  # which is 4*np.pi*R0/N
```

Correcting that, the end result is a circular shape, but with a different radius. I'm assuming that this is because of the reduced number of iterations (20000 instead of 1000000).

Edit:
As expected, using the correct number of iterations results in a plot similar to your expected one.

[image: python result]